# download sting data from both http and https servers in monotouch(detecting a host is working with https or not)

Tags: c#, http, https, xamarin.ios, ios6.0

I'm using monotouch for developing my iOS application for iOS 6+ . The basis of the applications is downloading some data from serveres that user introduce.

This servers may work with http or https. I use below code for downloading:

```
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest _HttpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create (Url);
            _HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
            _HttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
            _HttpWebRequest.Timeout = 15000;
            _HttpWebRequest .Method ="GET";

            System.Net.WebResponse _WebResponse = null;
            _WebResponse = _HttpWebRequest.GetResponse ();
            System.IO.Stream _WebStream = _WebResponse.GetResponseStream ();
            var bytes = HelperMethods .ReadToEnd (_WebStream);
            _WebResponse.Close ();
            _WebResponse.Close ();

            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

it works when the server are `http` but when the servers are `https` I should add `https://` before the host name for working. So how can I detect that whether a host is working with https or http, before sending requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot; and there is nothing whatsoever that says that `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` need to represent the same information, although by convention it almost always does. If you are content to assume that the two are equivalent, you'll just need to try both (or at least, decide which to try *first*).

Comment: Thank for the reply. but how a browser know that should add a http ot https before loading a webpage?

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad it doesn't "know"; it might try both, defaulting to one or the other first; it might try *what you used last* if you've visited before; it might try and get redirected; there are also IIRC some meta tags you can use (once you've been there before) to guide a browser to prefer one over the other, but that is again using knowledge from previous visits